# Why does the function definition and doctring show twice when I hover over the function in VS Code? How to resolve to showing once?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, docstring

On hovering the mouse pointer over a function, whether inbuilt or custom, the definition and docstring of the function shows as expected, however it shows twice.  I have had a search for what might be causing this and looked around my settings, but have yet to find a reason for it.  If it makes a difference, am using Python on VSCode.

Perhaps someone knows what might be causing this and how to resolve?  I have not attached any images, since I think the issue is quite clear, but happy to provide if needed for clarification.

Thanks!

Comment: disable extensions to see who generates what part of the hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling the **Jupyter** extension seems to fix it for me.

Update: Enabling the Jupyter extension and setting this also does the trick:

```
"jupyter.pylanceHandlesNotebooks": false
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure still what caused the issue, but disabling and then re-enabling the Pylance extension has solved this.  Thanks.

Comment: In fact the issue has returned today, so this simple action has NOT solved the issue.  Still investigating.